# Handle unbalanced parenthesis in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am not very good with regex. I used the following regex to replace a particular word from a string only if the word did not appear within quotes.

```
re.sub(r'("[^"]*")|%s' %word, lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "", query)
```

It works pretty good. Except that when `query = MBA in Human Resource Management (Jaipur National University)` , I get the following error.

```
error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

The value of word at this instance is (Jaipur

How can I fix the regex to handle unbalanced parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when `word` is `"(Jaipur"`, your regex is `r'("[^"]*")|(Jaipur'`, but you want it to be `r'("[^"]*")|\(Jaipur'`. To fix this, you can use `re.escape(word)` instead of just `word`:

```
re.sub(r'("[^"]*")|%s' % re.escape(word), lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1) else "", query)
```

(See [the documentation for `re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape).)